# Python to pick names based on a value from an Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write a python program to create a list of selected students (in the form of an Excel sheet) based on their marks. The student details are in the form of an Excel sheet (named  "data.xlsx") with two columns; one column for name and the second column for marks.

I wrote a code to list student marks which are above 80%, and the code is:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
if sheet.cell(row, 0).value >= 80:`
    data1 = [sheet.cell_value(row, 18) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')
for index, value in enumerate(data1):
    sheet.write(index, 1, value)
workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```

I face two issues:

1, The data arrays (data1 and the output excel sheet) lists all the entries (ie marks), instead of only listing the marks above 80 %

2, I do not know how to write the corresponding names (in the second column) with the students marks (in the first column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

data1 = [(sheet.cell(row, 0).value, sheet.cell(row, 1).value) for row in range(sheet.nrows) if sheet.cell(row, 0).value >= 80]

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')
for index, (val0, val1) in enumerate(data1):
    sheet.write(index, 1, val0)
    sheet.write(index, 2, val1)
workbook.save('output.xlsx')
```